# How do I get preg_replace to just replace the URL without any additional spaces or text which occur after the URL?

Tags: php, regex, wordpress, preg-replace

Here is my code:

```
function prepare_url($text) {
    if (strpos($text, 'youtu') === FALSE) {
        $url = "\\2";
    } else {
        $url = "<br><div id='".$playerid."'>Loading the player ...</div><script type='text/javascript'>jwplayer('".$playerid."').setup({flashplayer:'/jwplayer/player.swf',file:'".$text."',height:240,width:400});</script><br>";
        return $url;
    }
    $text = preg_replace("#(^|[\n ])(([\w]+?://[\w\#$%&~.\-;:=,?@\[\]+]*)(/[\w\#$%&~/.\-;:=,?@\[\]+]*)?)#is", "\\1<a href=\"\\2\" target=\"_blank\">".$url."</a>", $text);
    $text = preg_replace("#(^|[\n ])(((www|ftp)\.[\w\#$%&~.\-;:=,?@\[\]+]*)(/[\w\#$%&~/.\-;:=,?@\[\]+]*)?)#is", "\\1<a href=\"http://\\2\" target=\"_blank\">".$url."</a>", $text);

    return $text;
}
```

This code is working only if nothing occurs after the YouTube URL being replaced. Everything after the Youtube URL being replaced is added as part of the $text variable making it unusable. What can I do to make the preg_replace stop as soon as it hits the end of the YouTube URL? That is as soon as it hits a blank space?

Any help would be much appreciated :)

Comment: But the string $url has no any url. URL means something like -http-://yyy.yyyy.yyy or -http-://yyy.yy

Comment: correct, there is a variable called $url... You probably misunderstood the question. This code is working as in: it replaces the correct string with the correct string only additional characters are added after I want it to end (spaces whatever the next text is etc...)

Comment: @TR4NSeND can you post an example string of `$text`? There is likely an easier and more efficient way of getting the URL without using regex. Possibly using PHP's DOMDocument or path functions.

Comment: Here is an example when it works:                                  <script type="text/javascript">jwplayer('container1739').setup({flashplayer:'/jwplayer/player.swf',file:http://youtu.be/MTx6ha6fRwo',height:240,width:400});
</script>

Comment: Here is an example when it DOES NOT WORK and adds text which occurs next:     <script type="text/javascript">jwplayer('container1739').setup({flashplayer:'/jwplayer/p‌​layer.swf',file:youtu.be/MTx6ha6fRwo SPACE PLUS ADDITION TEXT FROM POST OCCUR HERE MAKING SCRIPT INVALID',height:240,width:400}); </script>

Comment: @TR4NSeND, no an example of the value of $text that is passed to function `prepare_url($text)` before you do any modifications to it.

Comment: Ah... this may be the problem   $text is used in several functions to mean different things... I will try a new variable to assure that the other values are not causing problems...

Comment: Tried a different variable with the same results... What should the value of $text that is passed to function prepare_url($text) be?

Answer (score 0):

This function I wrote a while back will take any text you input and set up the urls for emails links or embed a youtube video. It will remove the trailing characters of the youtube url. Hope it helps:

```
function MakeAutoLink($string)
{
        /** Add http:// **/
    $string = preg_replace("/([^\w\/])(www\.[a-z0-9\-]+\.[a-z0-9\-]+)/i", "$1http://$2",$string);
        /** make all URLs links **/
    $string = preg_replace("/([\w]+:\/\/[\w-?&;#~=\.\/\@]+[\w\/])/i","<a rel=\"nofollow\" target=\"_blank\" href=\"$1\">$1</A>",$string);
        /** make all emails hot links **/
    $string = preg_replace("/([\w-?&;#~=\.\/]+\@(\[?)[a-zA-Z0-9\-\.]+\.([a-zA-Z]{2,3}|[0-9]{1,3})(\]?))/i","<A HREF=\"mailto:$1\">$1</A>",$string);
        /** The Regular Expression filter **/
    $youtube_video = "/v=(.+?)&/";
        /** Check if there is a url in the text **/
    $video = preg_match_all($youtube_video, $string, $match);
    if ($video)
        { 
            $links=$match[0]; 
        for ($key=0;$key<$video;$key++) 
            { 
                $newstring = $string.'<br /><br /><iframe title="YouTube video player" class="youtube-player" type="text/html" width="320" height="185" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/'.substr($links[$key], 2,11).'" frameborder="0" allowFullScreen></iframe><br />';
                return $newstring;
            } 
        } 
    return $string;
}
```

**Drop this on your server and navigate to it for testing:**

**video.php**

```
    <?PHP
function MakeAutoLink($string)
    {
            /** Add http:// **/
        $string = preg_replace("/([^\w\/])(www\.[a-z0-9\-]+\.[a-z0-9\-]+)/i", "$1http://$2",$string);
            /** make all URLs links **/
        $string = preg_replace("/([\w]+:\/\/[\w-?&;#~=\.\/\@]+[\w\/])/i","$1",$string);
        $youtube_video = "/v=(.+?)&/";
            /** Check if there is a url in the text **/
        $longurl = preg_match_all($youtube_video, $string, $match);
        if ($longurl)
            { 
                $links=$match[0]; 
            for ($key=0;$key<$longurl;$key++) 
                { 
                    $newstring = "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=".substr($links[$key], 2,11);
                    return $newstring;
                } 
            } 
        return $string;
    }

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
 <?PHP
 if(isset($_POST['video']))
    {
        echo MakeAutoLink($_POST['video']);
    }
    else
        { 
 ?> 

 Try these two links:<br>
 http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1rqQQkcB0MY<br><br>
 http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1rqQQkcB0MY&some more text<br>
 <div align="center">
 <form method="post" action="<?php echo htmlentities($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);?>"> 
    <label>video:</label>
    <input type="text" title="Youtube video" name="video" size="60" value="" autocomplete="off" autofocus>
    <br><br>    
    <input class="login" type="submit" name="login" value="Get Video">
 </form>
 </div> 
 <?PHP
 }
 ?>

  </body>
</html>
```

This willconvert the url if it has other options after the video id using the "&". if you want it to stop as soon as it finds the first space, replace **/v=(.+?)&/** with  **/v=(.+?) /** making sure to leave an empty space between ) and /

Comment: Thanks for the answer, however as soon as i add the above code the page fails to load even without calling the function...

Comment: what errors are you getting, just tested this to make sure and is working fine on my server

Comment: didn't notice errors, just all Wordpress content (sidebars, main content etc..) were absent. Could be specific to my unique setup of theme + plugins. I am working within a custom plugin inside the Wordpress (3.5) Loop, but the Wordpress code doesn't replace embeds as it does outside the plugin loop. It would be perfect to just call the Wordpress embed replace function within the plugin. That is what I am looking into. I do appreciate the code, I'm sure it works, just not with my particular combination...

Comment: Okay look at my code from $video down. Do not try to stop the url at a certain point, accept it all and extract the portion that you want with substr(). a proper youtube url is the 2 to 11th character

Comment: Gotcha, I could use a good chunk of what is there to get the desired result. Going to try using from $video down and some other combinations of your code and mine together, I'll post if I get it going properly

Comment: rewriting it now will have it to you in a little while

Comment: @TR4NSeND Just updated post with a working example that will return base url regardless of the YouTube url length.